# How should I read or write APIC register "APIC_ICR"?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, hardware, driver

Here is the code:

```
static int __init test3_init(void)
{
   uint64_t v,i;
   for (i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
       v= native_x2apic_icr_read();
       printk("v=%llx\n",v);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And here is the result:

```
[ 6658.458919] v=9a557fd8
[ 6658.458925] v=1d
[ 6658.458928] v=17
[ 6658.458930] v=17
[ 6658.458932] v=17
[ 6658.458935] v=17
[ 6658.458937] v=17
[ 6658.458939] v=17
[ 6658.458942] v=17
[ 6658.458944] v=17
```

Why consecutive reading of the value of this register looks like this. The first two are different, but the remain are the same.

My final goal is to reset APIC_DM_NMI(0x00400) in this register, but if the value is not consistent, what is the point to reset the bit? Someone told me Resetting this bit APIC_DM_NMI can enable NMI from APIC, I don' know, I am totally a newbie. If anyone could provide any information on this MSR, and how to manipulate it correctly will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I feel that the stable value (i.e, 0x17) seems to be a more "normal" value. Can these output repeats? I mean, first two always different, and stable start from 3?

Here is the description of ICR register from [Pentium Processor System Architecture (page 395)](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=TVzjEZg1--YC&pg=PA370&lpg=PA370&dq=APIC+interrupt+command+register&source=bl&ots=iA4yONC0H5&sig=kkf8GULA30AALQfo34NO2zSbwCs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9bj2T531FIfeigfukq30Bg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%20interrupt%20command%20register&f=false), I didn't see any cautions about read this reagister.
[image]

FYI, here is the ICR register bit specification I found from a [lecture notes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.usfca.edu%2F~cruse%2Fcs630f06%2Flesson24.ppt&ei=nbf2T6WcB4uyiQeU45iBBw&usg=AFQjCNEyP2BWdEM0vJpBxFsdk4f4DMS39g&sig2=thlervRxQGOiLOz3ej6VoQ):
[image: ICR Higher 32 Bits]
[image: ICR Lower 32 Bits]

Comment: Yes, they can be repeated. So it is not ramdom. Besides, writing to that 0x400 bit result in a total different value.